# update table with another table with quite different structure

Tags: sql, oracle

Update table with another table with quite different structure

**Table A** :

| Name | Class | Subject | Marks | Address | City | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amit | 2 | maths | 34 | UK | JK | 5 |
| Ameer | 3 | english | 12 | CH | TW | 7 |

**Table B** :

| Name | Class | Subject | Marks | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amit | 2 | maths | 34 | 6 |
| Ameer | 3 | english | 12 | 9 |

Have done some calculation and now need to update the Age in Table A as compare the Table B

Primary Key:- for both the table is

Name
Class
Subject
Marks
Age

**Final Output for Table A** :

| Name | Class | Subject | Marks | Address | City | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amit | 2 | maths | 34 | UK | JK | 6 |
| Ameer | 3 | english | 12 | CH | TW | 9 |

Comment: Storing date of birth is a better idea than storing age. You already can present an age value within a query.

Comment: Yeah Get it , Please ignore the Age calculation , But how can i update table A wrt table B? because structure is different as table A has More Column than B ? can use join or group by or something else??

Comment: You can try `MERGE` with `WHEN MATCHED` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't store `AGE` as it changes every time it is someone's birthday.

Store date of birth, which is constant for each user, and you can use to calculate the age.

---

If you really do want to update it then:

```sql
MERGE INTO a
USING b
ON (a.name = b.name AND a.class = b.class)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET age = b.age;
```

Depending on what you want to match on then you could also add subjects and marks to the `ON` clause for the join.

Note:

- It would be better to have a unique primary key to identify each person.
- It would also be better to store the data in third-normal form (3NF) as name, class, address, city and date-of-birth are specific to a user but a user may have many subjects each with marks so you are going to repeat the name, class, address, city and date-of-birth data in every row. Don't do that; split the data into multiple tables in 3NF.